# get all data in json column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have an array data in a column

```
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | product_information                                                           |
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | {"product_size_id":10771,"product_size":"xxl","product_code":"BU0112-0102     |
    |   0001","product_preorder_date":"27\/10\/2020"}                               | 
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | {"product_size_id":9954,"product_size":"Super Single","product_code":         |
    | "BU0321.0101.0003.1"}                                                         | 
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

i want to do filter to get all data if there is ''product_order_remark" in product_information column

currently my query is

```
 return $query->whereJsonContains('product_information', 'product_preorder_date');
```

but it not return anything..

Comment: what is the column dataType?

Comment: @SureshKamrushi its 'text'

Comment: Why are you storing data like this? It isn't a good way to structure a relational database. (There are use cases for using JSON, and newer mySQL has a JSON column type, but this doesn't appear to be one of the sensible uses.)

Comment: @SureshKamrushi The column datatype should be JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
 return $query->whereNotNull('product_information->product_preorder_date');
```

Comment: Don't give answers which you are not sure. such as: `try` `maybe this will work` ...etc. try putting a comment first

Comment: "Try ..." [is an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386902/1364007). It may not be a good answer and it may not even be correct, but it is an attempt to answer the question - it's conceivable that the OP could find this useful and accept this as an answer. Clearly this answer would benefit from some explanation, but that doesn't make it worthy of deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(product_information , '$.product_order_remark')) as product_order_remark FROM `tableName`
```

I am assuming 'product_information' column is json type.